# Is running an entertainment website haram?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, sharia

Is it haram to open an entertainment website?

I have an entertainment website where I post the latest news about celebrities, is it haram to do so?

Answer (score 0):

If your posts doesn't contain bodies of womans, music, fitnah (that could harm someone that used to do something and you remind them of that. "ex : romantic pictures") and i think you should not post any wrong information or bad ones so you don't backbite them, better we don't be a reason to reveal "sitr of allah" from people.